# console application exit method not working

Tags: c#, .net, methods, exit

exit method not working while pressing q return with exception handle error.its a console application should i used both application.exit() and envoirnment.exit() . both doesn't work . am i doing something wrong . help will be really appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace calculator_extended
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int d = 0;

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Press A for addition");
                Console.WriteLine("Press S for subtraction");
                Console.WriteLine("Press M for Multiplication");
                Console.WriteLine("Press D for Divide");
                Console.WriteLine("Press q for Exit");


                char c = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

                int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                int b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                switch (c)
                {
                    case 'A':
                    case 'a':
                        {
                            d = add(a, b);
                            Console.WriteLine(d);
                            break;


                        }


                    case 'S':
                    case 's':
                        {
                            d = sub(a, b);
                            Console.WriteLine(d);
                            break;
                        }

                    case 'M':
                    case 'm':
                        {
                            d = mul(a, b);
                            Console.WriteLine(d);
                            break;
                        }

                    case 'D':
                    case 'd':
                        {
                            d = div(a, b);
                            Console.WriteLine(d);
                            break;
                        }

                    case 'q':
                        {

                            Environment.Exit(0);
                            break;

                        }
                    default:
                        {

                            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the correct Character");
                            break;
                        }



                }
            }
        }
            private static int add(int a, int b)
    {

                   return a + b;
    }
               private static int sub(int a, int b)
    {

                   return a - b;
    }
               private static int mul(int a, int b)
    {
                   return a * b;
    }
               private static int div(int a, int b)
    {

                   return a / b;
    }



        }
    }
```

ok this worked thanks guys for help can you check and let me know if the code is perfect and i am not missing something.thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace calculator_extended
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int d = 0;

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Press A for addition");
                Console.WriteLine("Press S for subtraction");
                Console.WriteLine("Press M for Multiplication");
                Console.WriteLine("Press D for Divide");
                Console.WriteLine("Press q for Exit");


                char c = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
                if (c == 'q')
                {
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }
                int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                int b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                switch (c)
                {
                    case 'A':
                    case 'a':
                        {
                            d = add(a, b);
                            Console.WriteLine(d);
                            break;


                        }


                    case 'S':
                    case 's':
                        {
                            d = sub(a, b);
                            Console.WriteLine(d);
                            break;
                        }

                    case 'M':
                    case 'm':
                        {
                            d = mul(a, b);
                            Console.WriteLine(d);
                            break;
                        }

                    case 'D':
                    case 'd':
                        {
                            d = div(a, b);
                            Console.WriteLine(d);
                            break;
                        }


                    default:
                        {

                            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the correct Character");
                            break;
                        }



                }
            }
        }
            private static int add(int a, int b)
    {

                   return a + b;
    }
               private static int sub(int a, int b)
    {

                   return a - b;
    }
               private static int mul(int a, int b)
    {
                   return a * b;
    }
               private static int div(int a, int b)
    {

                   return a / b;
    }



        }
    }
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not helpful at all.

Comment: maybe it is because your application waiting for 2 numbers after you press "q"?

Comment: yup dor i passed two arguments in function.but is there any way i can solve this?

Comment: Also use ToUpper(Char) or ToLower(Char). Saves you checking for both lower and upper cases.

Comment: @Science_Fiction unless Char comes out as null......

Comment: @BobVale Yeah some error checking to be done. Has to be there anywhere, how it is currently an exception could be thrown.

Comment: Yep, those `Convert.ToX(Console.ReadLine())` statements need breaking up to first retrieve the string value and then attempt to parse it to whatever type.

Comment: @Geek Have you tried using return instead, as per my answer? Additionaly as you are using Console.ReadLine are you pressing enter after you type `q`?

Comment: thanks bob for answere yes i am experimenting with all of them :) yes i am pressing enter after q

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe it is because your application waiting for 2 numbers after you press "q"?

try to change your code, remove case "q" and replace:

```
char c = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
```

with the following:

```
char c = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
if(c.ToLower() == 'q')
{
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Of course, just returning from the main function in a simple console application will also exit....

Comment: guys check second code and reply . thanks for help you guys are awesome

Answer (score 1):

```
char c = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
// you will need to Exit here if char is 'q'
// else it is expecting to read more entries below before it reaches your "case"
int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `Environment.Exit()` this should work normally.

Comment: yup i tried.but how i can solve the exception handle error.the error is i think because i am taking two input from user which is necessary for arthematic ops.is there any way to solve the error

Comment: He's already using `Environment.Exit`.  Setting an explicit return code doesn't change anything, the problem is likely he's reading two more characters before processing the command after reading the command character.

Comment: Ok, then check first if `c == 'q'` and exit the application then before you enter the integers in your console application.

Answer (score 0):

This bit of code

```
char c = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine()); 
int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); 
int b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Reads 3 lines from the console.

You probably want

```
char c = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine()); 
if (c=='Q' or c=='q') return;
int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); 
int b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: ok can you explain what is return using for here sorry i am new.what i know is the compiler check the code line by line so as you mentioned it is taking three lines.what will return do here ? thanks

Comment: @Geek the return statement will tell the function to return and stop processing.  As the function is the entry point for your console application this will cause the application to exit.  The only exception to this would be if you start doing stuff with background threads.

Comment: thanks bob for explaining.hehe nop its too early for me for background threads :P but thanks really appreciated your help :)

Answer (score -1):

Just change your code like that

```
bool exitLoop = false;
while(exitLoop) {
    ...
    case 'q':
        {
             exitLoop = true;
             break;
        }
    ...
}
```

Comment: The issue is because it's reading 3 lines from the console, rather than the exit function failing

Comment: Reading 3 lines is really not the problem! Use my code and you don't need to force the application to an exit.

Comment: you don't have to force an application exit, you can just `return` instead of `break`.  The problem arises because the OP the checking for 'q' is not processed until after the other two additional readlines to populate `a` and `b`